# Need advice on creating graphically plotted drawings using Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I would like some advice on how to create simple drawings/shapes that I can create by plotting points.

My aim is draw a simple bike chassis of which the dimensions can be altered by changing numbers in text-boxes. I previously achieved this simply by using a line chart in Visual C++, however this limits how good the drawing can be as it doesn't allow you to create shapes such as rectangles which can be filled in with colour, therefore the entire drawing consisted of lines of different weight.

I was wondering if there were any other features or add-ons for Visual Studio which could allow me to have this text-box value controlled drawing within a windows form.

Any advice would be much appreciated as I'm still very new to programming. Thank you for your time,
Aaron.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest and perhaps the most sound advice that I can give you for your problem is to start using a basic graphics library in your application. In my opinion a good choice for beginners would be Allegro. With it you will be able to draw basic 2D shapes pretty easily and comes with a load of tutorials. Give it a try.

http://alleg.sourceforge.net/readme.html